# spring boot MVC is not loading the redirected page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot MVC in my application. I need to redirect the user to `invalid-token.html` page, if the token is invalid. When the token is invalid, the url is changes in the browser, but, the invalid-token.html page does not load.

I have configured the `security` to allow for `/invalid-token` path and also have the `invalid-token.html` file inside the resources directory.

Do I also need to have a controller mapping for `/invalid-token` path inside my controller?

```
@GetMapping("/confirm")
    public RedirectView confirmUser(RedirectAttributes attributes, @RequestParam("token") String token){
        // Find the user associated with the reset token
        Optional<User> optionalUser= userService.findByConfirmationToken(token);

        if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            //redirect user to reset password page.
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("invalidToken", "Invalid Token. Please enter your email address.");
            return new RedirectView("redirect:invalid-token");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input parameter to `RedirectView` is incorrect, it should be `RedirectView("/invalid-token.html")`. If you look at the [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html), it takes `String url` as a parameter.

Comment: I have changed to `/invalid-token.html`. I am now getting a 404.Should I write a `GetMapping` method inside my controller for this?

Comment: Your html file(s) should be located under `src/main/webapp` folder

Comment: You can check my sample [github project](https://github.com/amithkumarg/restapi-springboot-jpa) for code reference. Its a spring boot project, and I have just now added a redirection example under `DefaultController` for your reference.

Comment: Its working now. So, in essense, the files are under resources, it should go through the controller and if the files are in webapp, it will not go through the controller mapping. Is this right.

Comment: Its not entirely true, you can also have static resources placed in these directories: `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/index.html`
`src/main/resources/resources/index.html`
`src/main/resources/static/index.html`
`src/main/resources/public/index.html`. Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located from any of the above locations.

Comment: So If I have a static html page inside `src/main/resources` directory, how can I redirect to the page from the controller.

Comment: You will have to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to add your custom path. [Ex](https://github.com/rebel-alliance/spring-boot-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alliance/rebel/tomcat/StaticResourceConfiguration.java)